# Finding the Trace and Determinant with Vieta's Formulas

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

In studying resultants in the context of proving Bezout's theorem in *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach* (by Garrity et al), I finally understood the proofs, motivation, and reasoning behind [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). The thought occurred to me that the Vieta formula for the constant coefficient is the "determinant" of the roots of the polynomial, and that the formula for the $(n-1)$th coefficient is like the "trace" of the roots of the polynomial.

But then I realized, that if the roots were actually eigenvalues, then they literally would be (up to a minus sign) the determinant and trace of some linear operator.

> The determinant and trace of a linear operator can be "read off" from the coefficients of its  characteristic polynomial.
>
> **Claim:** This result is just a special case of Vieta's formulas.

Is this correct? Or am I over-simplifying something here? I'm 95% sure that it is right, but I just want to double check, since Vieta's formulas are something I learned for the first time in high school, so this seems almost too good to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact true. The constant term in the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the product of all of the eigenvalues ($A$'s determinant), and the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ is always the sum of the eigenvalues ($A$'s trace).

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply -- thank you so much for your help!